# SQL Server Job Scheduler : error while updating data

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to update data of a table using Job Scheduler in sql server 2012. 
the following query is being executed:

```
UPDATE COM_TB_Inventory
        SET Location = 'Transit'
    WHERE Location = 'On Order' AND SDate IS NOT NULL 
        AND CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(DATETIME,SDate,103)) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
```

Here, 'sDate' field contains date but it's a varchar type of data field. If I execte this query manually then it works. But the scheduler is not working. I'm getting the following error:

> Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. Warning: Null value is
>   eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation. [SQLSTATE 01003]
>   (Message 8153)  Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not
>   permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the
>   subquery is used as an expression. [SQLSTATE 21000] (Error 512)  The
>   statement has been terminated. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 3621).  The
>   step failed.

a little help will be much appreciated. thnx

Comment: Are you sure this is the T-SQL statement that is generating the errors and the warning?

Comment: yes because this is the only step of that job and there isn't anything else in the query being executed

Comment: Have you got any triggers on the table? As stated that T-SQL statement can't throw that error.

Comment: yes there is a trigger but that's working fine. in fact, just now I've checked that this scheduler works perfectly in case there is only one row to update...but if there are multiple rows to update then it throws that error.

Comment: @ZoeHime you should post the code of the trigger instead.

Comment: solved it using cursor to update one row at a time..trigger wasn't an issue as I said earlier :)